# Solr - using result value from ''let"

Tags: variables, curl, solr, let

When I call solr using curl:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/colection/select?q="*:*"&rows=5&fl=$result&let=(result:ceil(mul(dist(2,v0_d,v1_d,v2_d,0.01595742627978325,0.010839935392141342,0.04199044033885002),1000)))"
```

I receive this error:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":400,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "fl":"$result",
      "let":"(result:ceil(mul(dist(2,v0_d,v1_d,v2_d,0.01595742627978325,0.010839935392141342,0.04199044033885002),1000)))",
      "rows":"5"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError"],
    "msg":"Error parsing fieldname: Missing param result while parsing function '$result'",
    "code":400}}
```

I define `result` in `let=(result:ce...`, but I can not use `result` in `fl` or other place.

Any idea?

Comment: Where did you see anything about `let` being a query parameter? You might be thinking of parameter dereferencing: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/local-params.html#parameter-dereferencing - not sure if that's supported directly in `fl`, but you could try. The only reference I know about in Solr for `let` is as a streaming expression, which would only be valid inside that streaming expression.

Comment: Setting Variables with let - https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_4/statistical-programming.html  Any idea?

Comment: Yes, that's about streaming expressions. If you're going to use that, you'll have to write a streaming expression and use it in that - it's not a general query parameter: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/streaming-expressions.html